# pre tag with h:outputtext

Tags: html, jsf, pre

is it possible to have a pre tag surrounding an h:outputtext as given below?

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">

  <h:outputText value="#{maintainBusinessProcessBean.featureCodeAssistContent}">   
  </h:outputText>

</pre>
```

I need to display the content of a java method in my html page. I tried giving some sample java method directly in my pre tag as given below it works fine.

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">

  public int getResult(int a, int b){
      return a+b;
  }
</pre>
```

whereas if i give the same method as a string to an h:outputtext and surround it with a pre tag, no formatting or syntax highlighting is happening. The java method content is just displayed as a text.

Comment: just a wild guess: does `escape="false"` on `<h:outputText>` help?

Comment: tried with escape="false", but no change. Still displays as plain text

Comment: for me it works just like in your first code block. have you compared html-outputs of both approaches? do you use a js-script just like me? please provide more code (backing bean, facelets)

Comment: You cannot add code in your view pages in JSF, that's something taken from old scriptlets ages. To display the result just put the method in server side and call it from the `outputText`.

Comment: Lester, now escape="false" works. First I tried in the main page. Then I tried displaying the method content in a popup (dialog). In dialog, syntax highlighting, new line and the tab space works fine. Thanks for your suggestion.. :)

Comment: yes, I am having my method in my backing bean and using the backing bean property with outputtext

Answer (score 1):

Surely it's possible. Escaping is even not necessary in this particular case as the output in the example doesn't contain any HTML special characters such as `<`, `>`, etc. Even more, it would definitely cause trouble (XSS attack holes and so on) when the output contains them. Your problem is caused elsewhere. Most likely you're simply executing the syntax highlighting script at the wrong moment. E.g. *before* the `<pre>` tag is declared in the HTML DOM tree:

```
<h:outputScript>prettyPrint();</h:outputScript>
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">#{maintainBusinessProcessBean.featureCodeAssistContent}</pre>
```

You should be executing it during window load

```
<h:outputScript>window.onload = prettyPrint;</h:outputScript>
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">#{maintainBusinessProcessBean.featureCodeAssistContent}</pre>
```

or at least in the end of the body as

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">#{maintainBusinessProcessBean.featureCodeAssistContent}</pre>
<h:outputScript>prettyPrint();</h:outputScript>
```

or

```
<h:outputScript target="body">prettyPrint();</h:outputScript>
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">#{maintainBusinessProcessBean.featureCodeAssistContent}</pre>
```